# Cloudflare with SSL & SagePay Server 5006 Error

Tags: ssl, nopcommerce, cloudflare, opayo

We have been battling with an issue where I've been getting a 5006 error using "SagePay Server" for 24 hours after moving a nopcommerce site to a new server with a different IP address.

We use a free cloudflare service with SSL enabled on Cloudflare in Full SSL mode and then a self signed certificate on our server so the connection is always secured end to end. This was also the same on the old server.

When moving servers we simply updated the IP address in couldflare to point at the new IP address but we started getting 5006 errors during the checkout process...

SagePay support told us they could not connect to our notification URL which was using SSL. Our server showed no attempt from their server to connect to ours yet SapePays log files show an "internal_error" with no more useful information.

However it is possible to the call the notification URL passed to SagePay from a browser and it works without issue.

Comment: We changed the notification URL to use http instead of https and then redirect back to https for our redirect page... This works, but does not resolve why SagePay can not work over SSL with Cloudflare.

Comment: One other thins to mention is that we are using SNI (Server Name Indication) so we can have many SSL websites on the same server with the same IP address... Perhaps SagePay does not support SNI.

Comment: Hi, you say you've moved server - I trust you've added the new IP address to sagepays whitelist? Otherwise it will error

Answer (score 1):

After talking with SagePay on several occasions it would seem the SagePay system does not support websites / traffic using SSL with SNI which means they can not connect to the notification URL over SSL.

In a time when IPv4 addresses are fast running out I would imagine more and more people will start to use SNI for SSL so they can run multiple sites using SSL from one IPv4 address - a massive oversight on SagePay's part me thinks.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to JaxUK, I can confirm SagePay does support SSL/TLS with SNI. Hope this helps someone

Comment: Did you speak directly to SagePay about this..? I'm waiting for a call back from them right now as I have a new IIS server using SNI and we're having issues that point to the SagePay notification POST not supporting SNI.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember the specifics. However, I do remember I managed to implement ssl.  Suggest looking at the error console in sage as will give you more info on the error